# Query Error - Anyone seen this before? _Click is not a known Data Ext or System View?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, data, sql

I've never seen this before, and the _Sent data view isn't working either.

Can someone confirm that I'm not crazy?

[image: WTF??]

Also, here's a simpler version of my query that also failed, that I have definitely used before (and also threw this error).

`Select 
    SubscriberKey
From _Click
Where URL like '%women%'`

Answer (score 0):

well...that didn't take long.

Because the Business Unit was under a parent, I decided to add the ent. prefix and now the query works.  This was definitely new to me, so hopefully if someone else gets this error they can find this to help them too.

Comment: If you did not add `ent.` in a child business unit if that is where your query is housed, then you would have just queried the child business unit data view, so I am bit confused as to how that fixed it?

Comment: I don't disagree that it's odd - but that was literally the change I made and it worked... well, the query passed SFMC validation but no records have yet to be returned.